Random forest regression: drop-column importance
I am running a random forest regression (RFR) task and I want to apply the Drop-column importance strategy. The basic idea of this strategy is:

to get a baseline performance score as with permutation importance,
but then drop a column entirely, retrain the model, and recompute the
performance score. The importance value of a feature is then the
difference between the baseline and the score from the model missing
that feature.

I found this strategy here and here.
Using the ranger package, how can I implement the above strategy and so in the end I could have the final model with the most important predictors (based on the above strategy) and maybe print the variables?
library(ranger)

train.idx <- sample(nrow(iris), 2/3 * nrow(iris))
iris.train <- iris[train.idx, ]
iris.test <- iris[-train.idx, ]

rg.iris <- ranger(Species ~ ., 
              data = iris.train, 
              num.trees = 101, 
              importance = "permutation")

Windows 11, R 4.3.3, RStudio 2023.12.1 Build 402.

Not sure you can do this using ranger only. To me it seems that the randomForest package would also be needed to evaluate the importance of the independent variables and then tune the model accordingly.

I think you could write a loop to do this, but you'd need to give some thought to what you're using to assess each model. Here's some code that assesses using Accuracy:
library(ranger)
library(data.table)

data(iris)
setDT(iris)
set.seed(1234)

# Function to assess performance, here based on Accuracy
performance <- function(model, data) {
  predictions <- predict(model, data.frame(data))
  return(mean(data$Species == predictions$predictions))
}

# Assess performance of baseline model
baseline_model <- ranger(Species ~ ., data = iris)
baseline_performance <- performance(baseline_model, iris)

# Loop to drop columns and assess performance
importance <- c()
for (feature in names(iris)[names(iris) != "Species"]) {
  model <- ranger(Species ~ ., data = iris[,!(names(iris) %in% feature), with = FALSE])
  performance_without_feature <- performance(model, iris[,!(names(iris) %in% feature), with = FALSE])
  importance[feature] <- baseline_performance - performance_without_feature
}

importance


So the results of the code are:
> importance Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width   0.000000000  0.006666667  0.013333333  0.006666667
I can conclude that Sepal.Lenght is uninmportant.
Actually I am interested in the Accuracy of the model at this stage.

So build your model again using just the features you want and calculate accuracy?

Yes, as @RYann says you can re-run the model with whatever features you want, and then assess performance. What threshold of importance you decide to use is subjective, so I've left it up to you. You could also easily modify the loop so it stores the performance_without_feature values if you wanted.
